# Javascript Append to Text File

Tags: jscript

I have several JavaScript files that when run return no errors, but do not do what is coded inside them.  This is one of them.  Is there something else I should have installed or enabled on the PC running the .JS files?

```
function WriteDemo()
{
   var fso, f, r;
   var ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2;
   fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
   f = fso.OpenTextFile("c:\\testfile.txt", ForWriting, true);
   f.Write("Hello world!");
   f.Close();
   f = fso.OpenTextFile("c:\\testfile.txt", ForReading);
   r = f.ReadLine();
   return(r);
}
```

Comment: That's JScript, not Javascript.

Comment: That file by itself won't do anything; the function is declared but never invoked.

Comment: 'but do not do what is coded inside them'. What does it do instead?

Comment: You should consider *not* doing this

Answer (score 2):

According to the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9ty6h50%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) on FileSystemObject, for JavaScript you should use

```
new ActiveXObject
```

instead of

```
CreateObject
```

(that's for VB).

```
function WriteDemo() 
{
 var fso, f, r;
 var ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2;
 fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
 f = fso.OpenTextFile("c:\\testfile.txt", ForWriting, true);
 f.Write("Hello world!");
 f.Close();
 f = fso.OpenTextFile("c:\\testfile.txt", ForReading);
 r = f.ReadLine();
 return(r);
}
```

And, of course, don't forget to call the function. :)

```
WriteDemo();
```

Comment: Ok, makes sense.  I am used to VBScript.  I thought the ActiveXObject was for calling something in IE.  Thank you Brian!

Comment: No problem. If this helped, you can mark it as the correct answer. Thanks! :)